# Using recursive to count the occurance of hi in a string

Tags: java, recursion

I encountered this problem:

> Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of times lowercase "hi" appears in the string.

```
count Hi("xxhixx") = 1   
count Hi("xhixhix") = 2   
count Hi("hi") = 1
```

I run my code and it works perfectly but is there any better way to do it ?
This is my code (Thank you in advance) :

```
public  int countHi(String string) {
    int count =0;
    return countHi(string,count);
}

public int countHi(String string, int count) {
    if(string.length()==0)
        return count;
    else {
        if(string.endsWith("hi"))
            count++;

        return countHi(string.substring(0, string.length()-1) , count);
    }
}
```

Comment: This Kind of question is better asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Since `"hi"` has a length of two characters finish the processing one step earlier: `string.length()==1`

Comment: Do you mean better way (whatever this means) but still recursively? Or still without a loop?

Comment: *return string.length() >= aString.length() ? (string.startsWith(aString) ? 1 : 0) + countAString(string.substring(1, string.length())) : 0;*

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `count` parameter, and in addition you can reduce the number of recursive calls by removing the last 2 characters of the `String` when they are equal to "hi":

```
public int countHi(String string) {
    if(string.length() < 2) {
        return 0; // no occurrences of "hi"
    } else {
        if(string.endsWith("hi")) {
            // one occurrence + the occurrences in the substring of the first length-2 chars
            return 1 + countHi(string.substring(0, string.length()-2));
        } else {
            // the occurrences in the substring of the first length-1 chars
            return countHi(string.substring(0, string.length()-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use string functions.This would be a ideal code.

```
  static int countRecursively(String string, int strCount, int count) {
    int strLength = string.length();
    if (strCount >= strLength) {
        return count;
    } else {
        if (string.charAt(strCount) == 'h' && (strCount + 1) < strLength && string.charAt(strCount + 1) == 'i') {
            count++;
            return countRecursively(string, strCount + 2, count);
        } else {
            return countRecursively(string, strCount + 1, count);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a single function, the following works.

```
public int countHi(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  if(len < 3)
  {
    if(len > 1 && str.substring(0,2).equals("hi"))
    {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  int counter = 0;
  if(str.substring(len - 2,len).equals("hi"))
  {
    counter = 1;
  }
  
  return countHi(str.substring(0,len - 1)) + counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem without a loop we need to use method recursion and inbuilt methods `contains`, `indexOf`, `substring`. Code is given below:

```
//I/P:"xxhixxhixxxhixxx";
//O/P:3

package Strings;

public class p24 {
//  logic 1 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="xxhixxhixxxhixxx";
    System.out.println(countHi(s));
}
public static int countHi(String s) {
    if (s.contains("hi")) {
        return 1 +countHi(s.substring(s.indexOf("hi")+2));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
//logic 2 for two string checking second string is present in first string. 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1="xxhixxhixxxhixxx";
    String s2="hi";
    System.out.println(countHi(s1,s2));
}
public static int countHi(String s1,String s2) {
    if (s1.contains(s2)) {
        return 1 +countHi(s1.substring(s1.indexOf(s2)+s2.length()),s2);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).